# How do I silently take down dogs in Far Cry 3?

Tags: far-cry-3

When taking on outposts or groups of guards in Far Cry 3, I'm constantly struggling to find a way to silently take down their pet dogs, so I can still earn the extra reward for handling an outpost without raising an alarm.

What methods can I use to silently take down guard dogs? Bonus points for versatility, or giving me multiple ways of handling the situation -- I might not always have access to a silenced pistol.

Comment: If this is anything like Saturday morning cartoons (and come on, what isn't), throw down some steaks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Note that the requirement for getting the full "Clear outpost without getting seen" bonus, is that they don't ***see*** you (this includes guard dogs, by the way). It doesn't matter how much they ***hear*** from you, your rocks, your guns and your explosives. Also, the alarm will only be triggered after a soldier saw you with his own eyes. You can make as much noise as you want, as long as they don't spot you. Yes, that's right - you can clear out an outpost by bombarding it with grenades and RPG rockets from a nearby cliff, and still get the 1500 exp bonus.

When you still want to take out the dogs without making a sound to avoid alerting the guards, there are silencers for most guns available (not just for pistols, but also for SMGs, some assault rifles and even for sniper rifles), and there is the recurve bow.

During most of the game, I always tried to carry at least one silent long-range weapon (sniper rifle or bow) and one silent automatic weapon (smg or assault rifle).

Comment: Exactly. High-powered silent long range weapon is the way to go. To get 1500xp, my preferred method throughout is bow -> silenced M700 -> Z93.

Comment: I continue to find it hilarious that attacking an outpost with 12 bad guys running around getting sniped, the survivors yelling "Sniper! Sniper!" while simultaneously being mauled by a bear is apparently not alarming enough to get them to pull the alarm.

Comment: @DanC You remember what happened to the last guy who set off a false Jason Brody alert for some random native with a rifle? They still haven't got the stains off of the ceiling.

Answer (score 1):

Land mines are a lifesaver, that's how I took the VERY first outpost undetected too. first, takedown everybody and make sure the dog is minding it's own business. sneak over to the back wall and place a landmine, then get far away before tossing a rock at the wall by the mine.

Answer (score 0):

Dogs have very good hearing, so if you throw a rock, a dog guard will hear it much further than a human guard would.

If the dog has an owner, the owner will follow along too, but the dog will usually stay there longer than the guard would, so kill the dog in that interval.

1. *Hide* outside the outpost
2. Throw a rock outside of it.
3. Check if the dog heard and is getting lured outside the camp. If not - get closer and re-start.
4. If a human guard follows the dog, wait for the guard to leave.
5. Kill the dog, silently, and from range.

You can try it inside the outpost too, but I wouldn't - it's *really* risky; dogs are fast and can detect you easily if you miss your shot or are too close (orientation seems to hardly matter).

Answer (score -1):

Lure the dog outside the base and slash it with your machete twice. I do this all the time, believe me I've taken over half the games map already doing this.