# What are effective ways to get a lot of experience (CP) when clearing an outpost?

Tags: far-cry-3-blood-dragon

In Far Cry 3, you get a [massive experience bonus when you clear an outpost without being seen](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/97401/4797). It seems that this is no longer the case in Far Cry 3: Blood Dragon.

Should I still attempt to clear an outpost stealthily? Is there another bonus or advantage to clearing an outpost without being seen?

**What are effective ways to get maximum or optimal CP when clearing an outpost in Far Cry 3: Blood Dragon?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There doesn't really seem to be much of a bonus for clearing an outpost stealthily.

In fact, the max CP from a base capture I've gotten was from this strategy:

- Run into the outpost like your face is on fire, and mash the green "Mega Shields" button to drop the shields, which spawns a Blood Dragon which rampages through the base
- Stay on the periphery of the chaos and execute takedowns and headshots on unsuspecting soldiers
- Once everyone is dead (or nearly so) find a mounted gun and off the Blood Dragon (worth a large bonus - 5000 CP per kill)

Once everyone is dead and the Dragon is out of the base or also dead, the base automatically comes under your control and you get the "base captured" bonus.

If there's no mounted gun, you can use a powerful weapon (the sniper rifle with explosive bullets, for instance) to off the Dragon, or you can wait for everyone to die, which spawns friendly snacks... err... scientists that will distract it while you get the kill.   Staying far away is also a good strategy - the Dragon's laser attack takes time to charge, so you can strafe out, take some shots, and strafe back before it fires.

Comment: Agreed.  In fact, once you get the laser upgrade to the assault rifle or you get the minigun, the best way of getting points is killing blood dragons.  The cost of the bullets, armor, and health can easily be recooped.  Just find lone dragons wandering around or find any outpost and hit the "Drop Megashields".  Then, profit.